# Busqueda Binaria Recursiva en C

Tags: c, recursión, busqueda

Debo hacer una búsqueda binaria con recursividad de un registro, pero me dice que el registro no existe cuando tengo la variable pos==-1 aunque ingrese un registro existente, y cuando la tengo en pos!=-1 solo me muestra el primero en la lista despues de ser ordenado.

Muchas gracias. Adjunto el código:

```
void particular(grupo g[100], int p, int l, int r, int idb) {
  ordenacion(g, & p);
  printf("Cantidad de grupos registrados: %d \n", p);
  printf("Ingresa ID a buscar: ");
  scanf("%d", & idb);
  int pos = bbin(g, idb, l, r);
  if (pos == -1) {
    printf("NO EXISTE  \n");
    getchar();
    getchar();
  } else {
    system("clear");
    pos = x;
    show(g);

    getchar();
    getchar();
  }
}

int bbin(grupo g[100], int l, int r, int idb) {
  int mid;
  if (l > r) {
    printf("No EXISTE");
    return -1;
  } else {
    mid = (l + r) / 2;
    if (idb < g[mid].mat) {
      return bbin(g, idb, l, mid - 1);
    } else {
      if (idb > g[mid].mat) {
        return bbin(g, idb, mid + 1, r);
      } else {
        return mid + 1;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes adjuntar el código de la función `ordenacion`? ¿Qué tipo de estructura es `grupo`? Apórtanos toda la información posible para poder depurar el código en nuestras máquinas.

Comment: Llamas a `bbin` con los argumentos `g`, `idb`, `l`, `r` (en ese orden) pero la función los espera en orden `g`, `l`, `r` e `idb`.